# Why is this true? $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^{k-1}}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{(k+1)k!} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my notes I have:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cfrac{s^{k-1}}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \cfrac{s^k}{(k+1)k!} $$

And maybe I am brain-dead, but I can't see how this was done?

Comment: Write out the first three or four terms of both sums and compare.

Comment: $(k+1)k! = (k+1)!$.

Comment: $k$ is a dummy variable. If you replace $k$ with $k+1,$ that gets you from the LHS to the RHS, along with xyzzyz's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By $m=k-1$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cfrac{s^{k-1}}{k!}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \cfrac{s^{m}}{(m+1)!}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \cfrac{s^{m}}{(m+1)m!}$$

Comment: Thanks for that :)

Comment: @codenoob You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \cfrac{s^k}{(k+1)k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \cfrac{s^k}{(k+1)!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cfrac{s^{k-1}}{k!}$$